# Nested method calls with Observable return value

Tags: rx-java

I have a workflow I'm trying to achieve using RxJava, as I'm pretty new with it I'm having a hard time understanding how to implement it.
This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
    Observable<String> methodA(String input){
       retValue = methodB(input);
       if(something){
         return retValue;
       } else{
         return methodC(input);
       }       
    }

    Observable<String> methodB(String input);
    Observable<String> methodC(String input);
```

I'm trying to use `map()` but actually I can't find a way that actually works.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.flatMap()` (if your condition depends on the results of methodB):

```
   retValue = methodB(input)
   .flatMap(item -> {
     if(something){
       return just(item);
     } else{
       return methodC(item);
     }
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use combination **filter/switchIfEmpty** if you want avoid old fashion **if**

```
  retValue = methodB(input)
            .filter(something)
            .switchIfEmpty(methodC(item))
```